# Resolving Path Differences Between Mac and Windows

Tags: java, file, path, directory, bufferedwriter

I am new to Stack Overflow and fairly new to programming, so hopefully this makes sense. I am writing a java program that creates a file in a specific directory. My program works on Windows and creates a file in the right location, but it does not work on Mac. I have tried changing the backslashes to a single forward slash, but that doesn't work. How should I change the code so that it works for Mac or ideally for both? I've put some of the code below.

Thanks in advance!

Class that creates new path for file:

```
try{
        //Create file path
        String dirpath = new ReWriterRunner().getPath()+"NewFiles";

        //Create directory if it doesn't exist
        File path = new File(dirpath);
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdir();
        }

        //Create file if it doesn't exist
        File readme = new File(dirpath+"\\README.md");
        if (!readme.exists()) {
            readme.createNewFile();
        }
```

Method that gets user input on where to put file:

```
public static String getPath(){
    String s;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the directory name under which the project files are stored.");
    System.out.println("Example: C:\\Users\\user\\work\\jhipstertesting)");
    System.out.println("Use double slashes when typing.");
    s = in.nextLine();
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use system properties to identify the system you are currently operating on ..
more info at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

but i would prefer using NIO. but that is your choice

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: Using system properties worked perfectly. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Forward slash "/" must be used to get the file path here. for ex.> Use:

```
File f = new File("/Users/pavankumar/Desktop/Testing/Java.txt");
f.createNewFile();
```